# Curl preg_match wrong code

Tags: php, curl

I try to learn cURL and i want to copy content from another page, but my code wrong:

```
preg_match("#<b> <a href="?p=Character&name=(.*?)&world=(.*?)" style='color: #fff;' title='level (.*?)'>(.*?)</a></b>#",
  $url, $lalala);
```

Who can fix that?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Comment: You can't have double quotes inside double quotes without escaping them with a backslash

Comment: You should better use DOM to parse HTML documents: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your doble quotes by `\` character inside your string.

```
preg_match("#<b> <a href=\"?p=Character&name=(.*?)&world=(.*?)\" style='color: #fff;' title='level (.*?)'>(.*?)</a></b>#",$url, $lalala);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are all mixed up -

```
preg_match('#<b> <a href="?p=Character&name=(.*?)&world=(.*?)" style=:"color: #fff;" title="level (.*?)">(.*?)</a></b>#',
  $url, $lalala);
```

Comment: Another warning:
Warning: preg_match() [ function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'f'

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're trying to parse complex HTML with regex. You really should be using a DOM library.

Comment: DOM looks very hard to me :/ i prefer cURL couse i need do it fast no time to learn DOM

Comment: DOM and cURL are two separate things. To parse HTML you need a DOM library, like [PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/). cURL is a communications protocol.